# How to find out if I have been removed from a friend's Yahoo! Messenger's contact list

Tags: chat, yahoo

Is there any way to know if someone has removed me from his/her Yahoo! Messenger friends list?

Comment: Why the downvote? Any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to find out if someone has done that.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo treats it private , you cannot know if others have deleted you or changed your name etc. It would be against security policy!

Comment: Why the downvote? Any explanation?

Comment: hey frnd sorry mixed up here with other question.. reversing it :)